# I can see it. vs I see it

Tags: modal-verbs

Could you explain it's necessary to use "can" in this phrase or I can say simply "I see it." Is there something changes if I use "I can see it."?

> Oh, dear! Where’s my key? I can’t find it. Oh look! It’s on the kitchen table. **I can see it**.

TIA

P.S. I have just read other posts about this question, and as I understand some difference may be. For example, "I can see these flowers!" (= your phisical ability) or "I see flowers" (= some flowers existence near you).

However, I don't understand is it recomended to use "can" with feeling verbs or not (very often it is used as I understand). And is there any difference if I use "can" in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying you 'can' see something might imply that you aren't looking at the thing at the moment of speaking. "I can see the oak tree from my window." doesn't necessarily imply that you're looking out the window at the tree at that moment, or even that you're in the room or the house with the window referred to.

But it's also used in cases where someone could just as well say "I see it'; I suppose there might be an implication that the speaker can NOW see it, where before that time they were looking for it but could not see it. But it doesn't change the meaning of the sentence by itself.